# How to automatically load checkbox if cell full?

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I'm trying to excel in creating a checkbox automatically if the cell in column A has a data. Also if from column A have data from A: 5 to A: 11 there should be 6 checkboxes, one for each full cell.
I have tried to adapt the following macro that takes the changes in column A but I have failed successfully.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim chkbox As CheckBox
    Dim cell As Range

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A10:A1000")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, Range("A10:A1000"))
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
                'If the cell is NOT empy, I should add a checkbox, to the right of the cell without text
                Set chkbox = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)
                With chkbox
                    .Text = ""
                End With
            Else
                For Each chkbox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
                    If Not Intersect(cell, chkbox.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
                        chkbox.Delete
                    End If
                Next chkbox
            End If
        Next cell
    End If

    Call LinkCheckBoxes

End Sub
```

Comment: In what way does this code not do what you want?

Comment: The issue is that the data in column A of the table are read-only and I can not modify them.
If I double click on the cell the checkbox appears but I would like to appear automatically if there is data in column A

thanks for your attention